# Batchable Apex and Limits

Tags: apex, batch, query, loop, bulk

I am confused on the wording of the documentation on Apex Batch Class: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm

I have my batch class querying for 200k records. To my understanding, it is in a batch class and it should chunk each `scope` list into 200 records, process those records then go back to the query and pull out the next 200 records. Is this incorrect? Should I be putting a `LIMIT 200` on my query? When I run the class and hit the webservice in `ConsoleApplicationLinkController.getShortenedLinkBULKNOTFUTURE()` for some reason it is hitting the service twice. See picture. It looks as if it is in a loop and is processing the previous batch of 200 processed records + the 200 new records. Does my code look right?

```
global with sharing class BatchBackFillContactsPardot implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.AllowsCallouts,Database.Stateful{
public List<String> valContactList = new List<String>();
global final String queryContact = 'SELECT Id,pi__url__c, Account.Web_Id_NatFund__c FROM Contact WHERE pi__url__c != NULL AND Account.Web_Id_NatFund__c != NULL AND Encrypted_Email_String__c = NULL ORDER BY Name ASC';
global String valContacts;
global String valLeads = null;

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator(queryContact);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, Contact[] scope) {
    for(Contact c : scope){
        valContacts = '{"ID":"' + c.Id+'","Properties":{"NFD":"' + c.Account.Web_Id_NatFund__c + '", "ContactId":"' +c.id+'","GeneratingTime":"' + Date.today().format() + '"}}';
        valContactList.add(valContacts);
    }
    if(valContactList.size()>1){
        valContacts = string.join(valContactList,',');
        system.debug('valLeads.length():: ' + valContacts.length() + ', bulk: ' + valContactList);
    }
    else {
        system.debug('list size is one');
    }
    try {
        ConsoleApplicationLinkController.getShortenedLinkBULKNOTFUTURE(valContacts, valLeads);
    }
    catch (System.CalloutException e){
        system.debug('Error: ' + e);
    }
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    system.debug('finished batchable:' + bc);
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is caused by using Database.Stateful and a class-level array. You're basically storing the execution of each previous run and adding to it. Here's how you'd fix that:

```
global with sharing class BatchBackFillContactsPardot implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.AllowsCallouts {
    // ... omitting start method ... //
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, Contact[] scope) {
        List<String> valContactList = new List<String>();
        for(Contact c : scope){
            String valContacts = '{"ID":"' + c.Id+'","Properties":{"NFD":"' + c.Account.Web_Id_NatFund__c + '", "ContactId":"' +c.id+'","GeneratingTime":"' + Date.today().format() + '"}}';
            valContactList.add(valContacts);
        // ... rest of code ... //
    }
    // ... omitting finish method ... //
}
```

In general, you should **only** use `Database.Stateful` when you need to aggregate data together across runs. Also, only use class-level variables when you need to share data across execute methods.